Decoding Australian Grid References: Conversion to Lat/Long Coordinates
I'm struggling to convert Australia grid references to latitude and longitude coordinates.
I've provided several grid reference - location pairings as examples.
Grid Reference - M 100A D8 (355762)
Location - https://www.google.com/maps/place/37+Davey+St,+Frankston+VIC+3199,+Australia/@-38.1463792,145.1210822,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x6ad674d862a819a7:0x910799a3443d7bb1!8m2!3d-38.1463834!4d145.1236571!16s%2Fg%2F11f4plx3r0?entry=ttu

Grid Reference - SVNE 5959 D7 (830339)
Location - https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lake+Catani+Campground/@-36.7349571,146.8106195,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x6b269b73f3ffffff:0xc725f4e656804697!8m2!3d-36.7349614!4d146.8131944!16s%2Fg%2F11kj8__6xp?entry=ttu

Grid Reference - M 205 A6 (908034)
Location - https://www.google.com/maps/place/10+Cyprus+Ct,+Wyndham+Vale+VIC+3024,+Australia/@-37.8926463,144.6190449,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x6ad6852541a78add:0x3d15e49a1a40566!8m2!3d-37.8926506!4d144.6216198!16s%2Fg%2F11c4prjbq4?entry=ttu

Grid Reference - M 41 J7 (135131)
Location - https://www.google.com/maps/place/120+Chirnside+St,+Kingsville+VIC+3012,+Australia/@-37.8100954,144.8794651,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x6ad66750effc5d11:0xc587f4022fb6a30e!8m2!3d-37.8100997!4d144.88204!16s%2Fg%2F11c27v30lq?entry=ttu

Grid Reference - SVSE 6825 C1 (927742)
Location - https://www.google.com/maps/place/160+Lye+and+Dixon+Rd,+Ripplebrook+VIC+3818,+Australia/@-38.1730173,145.7730944,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x6b29ebf3c09b2361:0x23e22f477b586ad5!8m2!3d-38.1730215!4d145.7756693!16s%2Fg%2F11csjj833w?entry=ttu

I'm unsure which grid system these references are based on and how to accurately convert them to geographic coordinates. If anyone has experience with this grid system, please help me find the solution.
I tried to convert Australian grid references to latitude and longitude coordinates using online tools and libraries, expecting to obtain accurate coordinates. Instead, I encountered errors and inconsistent results, leading me to seek guidance on the correct approach.
